# Can we remove extra space in yaml after colon in PyYaml

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a dictionary which looks like:

```
{'ab':8082 , 'bc': 8082}
```

When I dump it to python yaml, I want it to look like:

```
ab:8082
```

and not like:

```
ab: 8082
```

Is there a way we can achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your output is not valid YAML, as that requires a space after the colon in block style.

So what I recommend is post-processing the output using `ruamel.yaml`s `transform` argument to dump

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = {'ab':8082 , 'bc': 8082}

def remove_space_after_colon(s):
    res = []
    for line in s.splitlines(True):
       res.append(line.replace(': ', ':', 1))  # 1, to prevent replacing in values
    return ''.join(res)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, transform=remove_space_after_colon)
```

which gives:

```
ab:8082
bc:8082
```